# complex filter conditions with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The application passes 5 different filter conditions from the UI to the query. ie,`--STORE  CODE    DESC    NOTES   QTY.`

When I add these conditions with different possibilities it is coming very long, ie

```
--1 0   0   0   0
IF @Store<>'0' AND @code='' AND @DESC='' AND @Notes='' AND @QTY=0 
--1 1   0   0   0
--1 1   0   0   1
--1 1   1   0   0
--1 1   1   1   0
etc..........
```

is there any way to simplify this to pass as single query. Hope the question is understandable.

Sample code I have done as below,

```
SET @sql = 'Select * from tbl_store Where Inactive=0 ';
--10000
    IF @Store<>'0' AND @Code='' AND @Description='' AND @Notes='' --AND @Qty<>''
    SET @sql += ' AND Store=@Store  AND Quantity = @Qty';

    --11000
    ELSE IF @Store<>'0' AND @Code<>'' AND @Description='' AND @Notes='' --AND @Qty<>''
    SET @sql += ' AND Store=@Store  AND Code=@Code  AND Quantity = @Qty';
```

........................

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would place any validation outside of the query and simply filter your query as follows.

```
SET @IsValidFilter=<YOUR VALIDATION LOGIC HERE>--IF YOU CAN'T TRUST INCOMING VALUES

SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    (@IsValidFilter=1)
    AND 
    (@Store IS NULL OR MyTable.StoreID=@Store) 
    AND 
    (@code= IS NULL OR MyTable.CodeID=@Code)
    AND
    (@DESC IS NULL OR MyTable.Description=@Desc)
    AND
    (@Notes IS NULL OR MyTable.Notes=@Notes)
```

If you can't trust the values being passed in and need some logic based on a combination of parameters values then it would be more readable to create a @ValidFilter flag and simply add a final `AND @ValidFilter=1` and not do too  much in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Do them one at a time:

```
SET @sql = 'Select * from tbl_store Where Inactive = 0 ';
IF @Store <> '0' 
    SET @sql += ' and Store = @Store';
IF @Qty <> ''
    SET @sql += ' and Quantity = @Qty';
. . . .
```

For performance reasons, what you are doing is a good idea.  If an appropriate index is available, the ultimate `where` clause should be able to take advantage of appropriate indexes.  A single `where` condition such as this won't:

```
where (@store = '0' or start = @store) and
      (@qty = '' or quantity = @qty) and
      . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do away with the dynamic query if possible and do something like this:

```
select * 
from tbl_store ts
where ts.Inactive = 0
and (
    ( @Store <> '0' and @Description = '' and @Notes = '' and Store = @Store and Quantity = @Qty)
or
    (@Store <> '0' and @Code <> '' and @Notes <> '' and Code = @Code and Store = @Store and Quantity = @Qty)
);
```

Using dynamic queries, such as yours, can lead to security holes, and general confusion about how things are being done. In my opinion, it should be one of last resorts.